# Import my app react-native components into a single file like with vue?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native coming from a vue background, I was thinking is it possible to list all my app components into a file called components, this is because I find importing components into my pages, I store my components in separate folders (modals, forms...).

I vue I had my App.js file, in it I had something like this :

```
//app.js
Vue.component('layout-nav-3', require ('./components/layouts/LAYOUTnav3.vue').default);
Vue.component('layout-nav-responsive-2', require ('./components/layouts/LAYOUTresponsiveNav2.vue').default);
Vue.component('layout-button-1', require ('./components/layouts/LAYOUTbutton1.vue').default);
Vue.component('layout-button-2', require ('./components/layouts/LAYOUTbutton2.vue').default);
Vue.component('layout-link-1', require ('./components/layouts/LAYOUTlink1.vue').default);
```

I could then place all this components in my views without having to do an import like:

```
import POSTCard1from '../components/posts/POSTCard1'
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this. In react you should always import components